# A Cryptic Christmas Puzzle

Tags: phrase-requests

Whilst researching an answer to [*Combination Lock*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/477802/why-do-we-call-it-combination-lock), I was reminded of word puzzles such as the visual

[image]

popularized by newspaper puzzle pages and TV programs such as "Catchphrase". I am aware the modern term for such pictorial usage is [rebus** (n.)
c. 1600, from Latin rebus "by means of objects,"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/rebus) and according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus) can be traced back to similar usage in Egyptian hieroglyphics and possibly earlier.

**However** I seem to remember a form of cypher only using Latin letters but can't track such a reference. so for the example above it would look like

> AcToImObN

Note that it would not necessarily have upper lower case that is just my emphasis for clarity.

Can anyone put my mind at rest that it's not just a MfYi gMmIeNnDt (a figment of my mind) and, more importantly, what is this kind of puzzle or cypher called?

---

Hellion reminded me a similar form of **substituting some characters** for words is called a [Gramogram or grammagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramogram) (as may be used in text-speak) but that also is a more modern substitution. NOR were letters added, such as in [Pig Latin](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pig-latin). What I'm after is an older usage by just the "mixing" of original letters.

And microenzo has identified it as probably a form of plaintext [transposition cipher](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher), which at its simplest can be made by wrapping a strip round a [scytalae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scytale) former such as a pencil and with some variation (perhaps a Caesar cipher) that I still cant recollect would probably look like my garbled words.

**Final Edit**

It looks like it was a 2 line form of **Rail Fence Cipher** as used by the greeks on thier scytale from the answer by microenzo thus

"Now is the winter of our discontent"

after unwrapping would become

```
Nwi h itro u icnet
o stewne fordsotn.
```

Comment: If you're asking whether "AcToImObN" is still considered a rebus, my contention is [Yes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44003/what-is-xlnc-an-example-of/).  (Apparently, per the link, it is also called a "grammagram".)

Comment: The title of this page calls them Pictographs and has some good examples: http://www.fun-with-words.com/rebus_puzzle_explain.html I haven't found a dictionary that defines pictograph that way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for here. Is it a single word or phrase for the kind of puzzle you've pictured?

Comment: OK, but the important thing is that you need to specify that explicitly in your question, that you are looking for a single word for whatever it is you are talking about.

Comment: Just for the sake of accuracy, a Caesar cypher wouldn't give you the result you expect, because it is a *substitution cypher*

Comment: Are you answering _in_ your question? It's totally ok to provide an _actual_ answer in the answer space (and it is a better way to do it than in the question).

Comment: Again for accuracy, I wouldn't say it's rail fence. That does not mix letters from both /all words. If you try it with the original text (comb ation) you'd get *cmainobto*. Instead, I think it's a *columnar transposition* cypher. Typically you'd decide a width and you'd write out the message breaking it at the width you selected. You then go through the column. In your case you'd select width of 5 and you get what you expect (I'm ignoring padding). I don't seem to be able to make an example of this in the comment, I might edit the answer.

Comment: @KJO Oh, OK - I guess I might have misunderstood the question: the rail fence came to me almost immediately, but I discounted it for the reasons I mentioned :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand from the question that your query is about the word cypher, not the pictorial based puzzle.

From a cypher taxonomy point of view, what you describe is a *transposition cypher*, in particular i would say a type of *columnar cypher* (the latter point may be argued). You can find descriptions of this type of cypher readily on the web, but as usual Wikipedia is a good start:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher

However I think the question also refers to the relative word puzzle. I also can't find a reference to this type of *anagram*, as the searches for word puzzles/games are "polluted" by adverts for apps and board games. For what is worth, and I only report it here as a hint for further research, in Italian this type of puzzles is called *intarsio*, which translates as *inlay*.

Comment: What you describe is a *scytale*. I also can't find examples of the "inlay" technique in English - if, of course, it's called that.

Comment: @KJO Wrapping the message around a cylinder is called a [scytale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scytale) cypher.